# Proposta de sinônimo: [charset] para [character-encoding]

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

Temos a tag [charset](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charset), com três perguntas, e [character-encoding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding), com 12. Acredito que a primeira deveria ser sinônimo da segunda. Na verdade, acho que ambas deveriam ser sinônimas de [codificação-de-caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-caracteres), que não existe.

O que acham?

Comment: Aproveitando a oportunidade, aqui no meta tags-sinónimas e tags-sinonimas deveriam ser sinônimas de tags-sinônimas. Sinalizei esta pergunta pedindo ao moderador para fazer isso.

Comment: tags-sinónimas e tags-sinonimas maracadas como tags sinônimas de tags-sinônimas.

Comment: Sugiro também [tag:pagina-de-codigo] como usado no DOS e outros sistemas como Novel: http://www.novell.com/pt-br/documentation/nw42/docui/#../briw2ref/cncptptg/data/hk644x6b.html